# HTACCESS URL Re-write

Tags: php, .htaccess

How do I retrieve the abc123 part of the URL below with .htaccess please?

```
https://a.com/product/abc123
```

I need to use the abc123 part to create a query.
Ordinarily, I know this can be achieved with:

```
https://a.com/product/?key=abc123
```

and getting the abc123 part with $_GET like this:

```
$product_key = $_GET['key'];
```

but I would prefer the htaccess method, which I need help with.

Comment: please show your attempted code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put and play with this rule in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?product/(.*?)/?$ /index.php?key=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tested it now and it works. Look if the index.php is near .htaccess and if you do not use subfolders

Comment: After playing around with it, this worked: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product([^/]+)/(.+)$ product.php?key=$2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?$) ?key=$1 [QSA]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^(*+/?$) ?key=$1 [QSA]
```

Here you go !